# How to put shapes, lines, etc, into the details section (aka not the title section)?

Tags: discussion, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pasting in images](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309/pasting-in-images)

Do you have to go on Google images, copy and past like a shape into this website? Because that's great, but I would need to put more lines on it/draw them myself or whatever so tell me how you get shapes, lines and things like that into this box so that I can ask my questions for my geometry homework.

Comment: You can load images from the web or from your computer.  You click on the little box that looks like a scene and it will give you a chance.  I think it takes a little more reputation than you have.  Until then, if you post a link somebody will replace it for you.

Answer (score 1):

See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) for the detailed set of instructions. But heed the caveat:

> you need to be registered member in the site with at least 10 reputation in order to [gain the privilege to use this feature](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user).

As it stands your account currently does not have the sufficient reputation. As soon as two users upvote your questions (or if you post an answer and receive one upvote on it), you will gain that ability.